# Wordpress: Show categories the searched posts are in

Tags: wordpress, search, categories

I'm posting this question after looked on every site I found regarding this matter. None of the answers gave me a clue to solve this and google results are contaminated with completely different topics.

What I'm trying to achieve is to display the list of categories of the posts that search query returned.
The final idea is to achieve something like this. (please have in mind that each one of those cities is a category)

[image: Each one of the items is a category]

User will search for posts, then it goes to results where results are displayed. What I need to do is to find in what categories are all the posts returned in and try to do a post_count on each one of them to show how many posts (of all returned) are within that specific category.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have not provided **any code**, I tried in **my way**.I guess, It is not the **best way** to achieve it **but as of now**, you can do in that way.

Here, I have used `PHP` to achieve your **desired result**.

I have used **Twenty Fourteen** theme's `search.php`.

Here is **my code** for the `search.php` of Twenty Fourteen theme and you can implement in your `search file` :

```
    <?php
    /**
     * The template for displaying Search Results pages
     *
     * @package WordPress
     * @subpackage Twenty_Fourteen
     * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
     */

    get_header(); ?>

        <section id="primary" class="content-area">
            <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

                <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

                <header class="page-header">
                    <h1 class="page-title"><?php printf( __( 'Search Results for: %s', 'twentyfourteen' ), get_search_query() ); ?></h1>
                </header><!-- .page-header -->

                    <?php 

                        // Start the Loop.
                        $post_id_array = array(); //Blank array to store all Post IDs

                        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 

                            array_push($post_id_array, $post->ID); //store ID to array

                            /*
                             * Include the post format-specific template for the content. If you want to
                             * use this in a child theme, then include a file called called content-___.php
                             * (where ___ is the post format) and that will be used instead.
                             */
                            get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

                        endwhile;
                        // Previous/next post navigation.
                        twentyfourteen_paging_nav();

                        $catarray = array(); //Blank array to store all categories
                        $k=1;
                        foreach($post_id_array as $my_post){
                            $my_category = get_the_category( $my_post );

                            foreach($my_category as $my_cat){
                                array_push($catarray, $my_cat->cat_name); //Store category in array
                            }

                            $something = array_count_values($catarray); //Count total number of element in category array

                            foreach(array_unique($catarray) as $some){
                                if($k == sizeof($my_category) ): //Condition to print all thing if only it is last element of an array.
                                    echo $some."(". $something[$some].")<br>";
                                endif;
                            }
                            $k++;
                        }
                    else :
                        // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
                        get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );

                    endif;
                ?>

            </div><!-- #content -->
        </section><!-- #primary -->

    <?php
    get_sidebar( 'content' );
    get_sidebar();
    get_footer();
```

Here in above code, I have done :

**Step-1** : Take one **blank array** to store **ID of the posts** that are given by the search query.

**Step-2** : Push all the **IDs** in to created **blank array** with PHP's [`array_push`](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_push.asp) function. **NOTE:** Make sure you have put it in a `while loop` to get all the `ID`.

After **two steps**, now you have an **array of all the post IDs**.

**Step-3** : Take **another blank array** to store related **category name** of the post.

**Step-4** : Take **one variable** and give **its value** to `1` which is useful at the end.(I have taken `$k = 1`).

**Step-5** : Make one `foreach` loop of **Post IDs**. And **get** category name of the posts with wordpress function [`get_the_category`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category#Parameters).`It will fetch category based on post ID`.

**Step-6** : Now its time to **use** the **blank array** that we have created for category name.So just `loop` through category name and **store** name of the category in to an **array**.

**Step-7** : **Count** total names in the category array with PHP's [`array_count_values`](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_count_values.asp) function and assign variable to it.(I have used `$something`).

After **step-7**, we have an **array of category name**. **Note:** Here in this array, there might be **duplication** of category name.To **remove duplication** follow next step.

**Step-8** : Use PHP's ['array_unique'](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) function to get only **unique value** from an array.

**Step-9** : Make a `loop` of the **category name**.

If you `echo` right now, `it will print categories to total number of post times`.

So now its right time to **use** the variable that we have taken before `foreach` loop of post ID(`$k=1`).

**Last step** : Now make **one condition** to print **all categories** at the **last post**.

So for that I have used `if($k == sizeof($my_category) )` which means that, It will only print when length of an category array equal to the variable `K`(In short, in the end).

**Increas**e the value of `$k`.

Hope it helps you. Ask me If you have any doubt.

Comment: Hi Rohil, thank you so much for such a detailed answer. Yes, I didn't put any code because I was actually clueless, so putting something on my question would be more confusing than helping. I preferred to leave things starting on a standard loop to make things easier. I have tested the code, it didn't work for me yet, I deleted all I had and pasted it just like you sent it, I just replaced the call to content templates because I don't have them but nothing happened. All I'm getting are the post resulting from the loop but that's it. I will keep trying though.

Comment: Ok made it work, the issue I'm having now is that I'm getting a lot of search results under "Los Angeles" category but all I get is "Los Angeles (1)"

Comment: Hi Rohil, I have two doubts if you don't mind. What should I change in order to place this code outside the loop (my filters come first) and how should I do to include the link to the categories (I never worked with array_push() or array_unique() before).

Comment: [`get_category_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_link#Examples) will help you to get the link of categories.We have category names in an `array` and you can use them to get category ID and from the `ID` you can get link.
Sorry, I did not get your first point.